# Getting the h1 text content from a column in a row with a button click

Tags: javascript

How can I get the text content of the specific column clicked on using
JS only? I am familiar with iteration and the fact that by adding a
class or id to the tag or a onClick("") function call we can get its
content. But in this case we could have 20 items listed in a page and
there must be a way to get it otherwise. I searched the forum and most
of the examples were with jQuery. Thanks!

```
      <div class="row" id="gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <div class="column" >
          <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
          <h1>Pants</h1>
          <p class="price">$19.99</p>
          <p>Some text about the pants</p>
          <p><button >Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" >
          <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
          <h1>Pants</h1>
          <p class="price">$19.99</p>
          <p>Some text about the pants</p>
          <p><button >Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" >
          <img src="images/dress.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
          <h1 >Tailored dress</h1>
          <p class="price">$19.99</p>
          <p>Some text about the dress</p>
          <p><button >Add to Cart</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Your column seems to contain three H1s, which one do you want to get, and how have you set the click listener?

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: I have made several attempts, I  did not attach them since my goal was to learn new methods which are efficient and correct. Will do for next time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector` to get the `<h1>` tag and retrieve its `textContent`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.column').forEach(column=>column.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log(this.querySelector('h1').textContent);
}));
```

```html
<div class="row" id="gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Pants</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the pants</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Pants</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the pants</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/dress.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored dress</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the dress</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you helped me understand why it didn't work on my end, I did not put the . before the column in document.querySelectorAll('.column')

Comment: @Zoh No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, [gather all the columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to each one, then look for the heading element in question and retrieve it's [text content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). Like this:

```js
const columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column')

for (let c of columns) {
  c.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Capture the heading element
    const h1 = c.querySelector('h1');
    // Do something with it..
    console.log(h1.textContent);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="gallery" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Pants</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the pants</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/pants.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Pants</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the pants</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/dress.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <h1>Tailored dress</h1>
    <p class="price">$19.99</p>
    <p>Some text about the dress</p>
    <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```